# Did I correctly derive this recurrence equation formula

Tags: recurrence-relations

I started with the recurrence equation $\space\space  x_{n+1}=ax_n+b \space \space$ and turned it into the formula at the bottom to allow us to find the value of any nth term in the form $\space \space x_n=f(n)$

Here is how I derived my formula for $f(n)$:

$$x_0=x$$
$$x_1=ax+b$$
$$x_2=a^2x+ab+b$$
$$x_3=a^3x+a^2b+ab+b$$
$$x_n=a^nx+a^{n-1}b+a^{n-2}b...a^2b+ab+b$$
Refer to the geometric progression equation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}b=\frac{b(1-a^n)}{1-a}$$
$$x_n=a^nx+\frac{a^nb-b}{a-1}$$
$$x_n=\frac{a^{n+1}x-a^nx+a^nb-b}{a-1}$$
$$x_n=\frac{a^n(ax-x+b)-b}{a-1}$$
Final simplification and substitution of $x_0=x$
$$x_n=\frac{a^n((a-1)x_0+b)-b}{a-1}$$
Side Note: This idea originally came from problems I encountered in the Collatz Conjecture, eventually leading to create a general formula. Could this potentially be helpful to have other than my own personal use?

Comment: Your question in your post does not agree with the title.

Comment: Yes, this is right. It is called an arithmetico-geometric sequence. But this is an elementary and well-know result, nothing new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it easier. Considering $$  x_{n+1}=a\,x_n+b $$ let $x_n=y_n+c$ to make
$$y_{n+1}+c=a\, y_n+ac+b$$ that is to say
$$y_{n+1}=a\, y_n+(ac+b-c)$$  Choose $c$ such that $ac+b-c=0$ and you are back to the classical geometric sequence. Solve it for $y_n$ and go back to $x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear recurrence with constant coefficients and it can also be solved similarly to a linear ODE.

The homogeneous equation is

$$x_{n+1}=ax_n$$ and obviously has the general solution

$$x_n=ca^n.$$

Now a particular solution of the non-homegeneous equation

$$x_{n+1}=ax_n+b$$ is given by a constant, let $d$, such that

$$d=ad+b.$$

We have

$$x_n=ca^n+\frac b{1-a}$$ and we plug the initial condition $x=x_0$,

$$x_0=c+\frac b{1-a}$$ and finally

$$x_n=a^nx_0+\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}b.$$

---

Other method:

The relation $x_{n+1}=ax_n$ hints the transformation $x_n=a^ny_n$, leading to the modified recurrence

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+ba^{-n},$$ which is solved by the summation of a geometric series

$$y_n=y_0+b\sum_{k=1}^na^{-k}=y_0+a^{-1}\frac{1-a^{-n}}{1-a^{-1}}.$$

Then

$$x_n=a^nx_0+\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b.$$